# ESLint - ignore line from JS Parsing

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, eslint

Migrating from JSHint to ESLint for the ES6 / React support and running into an error.  I am writing Ruby in my JS files to generate some constants rather than AJAXing them from the back end, an example of this:

```
var myObj = { 
<% Requirements::COMPARATORS.sort.each do |k,v| %> */
    { code: '<%= escape_javascript k %>', name: '<%= escape_javascript v %>' 
<% end %>
}
```

This causes an error in ESLint

```
2:1  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token
```

in JSHint days I'd wrap with /* jshint ignore:start */, so:

```
/* jshint ignore:start */
  //some ruby code
/* jshint ignore:end */
```

However in using the disable / enable comments, this does not work and I still get an error.

```
/*eslint-disable*/ 
  //some ruby code
/*eslint-enable*/
```

Is this just a limitation on ESLint? is there any way to get around this? I've thought about writing a processor and strip out all ruby code that way, however I'm hoping for an easier / faster solution as this is really only in two - three files.

Thanks

Comment: This is working for me. `/* eslint-disable */ console.log(); /* eslint-enable */`

Answer (score 2):

The difference between JSHint and ESLint is that JSHint was linting files as it parsed them. So a comment would disable parser until it sees corresponding closing comment. In ESLint the whole file is parsed into AST first, and then processed. There is no way to disable parser for a few lines.
Your best bet is to create a processor (or see if somebody already created one) that would extract just javascript parts of your file.